# Set the value of a ReactiveForm in a Jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to learn how to unit test a reactiveForm in Angular.

what I want to do is set the value of a field and then check if the form is valid after adding the value.

This is where i've got to:

snippet from jasmine test

```
it('Filled in form is valid', async(() => {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      const component = fixture.componentInstance; 
      component.userForm.setValue({
        value:{
              firstName : ["Bob"]
              }
      })
 }));
```

the form:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">first Name:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
    </label>
    <label class="center-block">first Name:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="lastName">
    </label>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I get the following error message from Karma:

> Failed: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'firstName'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
component.userForm.controls.firstName.setValue('bob');
```

That will then set the form input to what you want.